# use record from same model as foreignkey in django

Tags: django, django-models

my model is as follows :

```
class Profile(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    full_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    husband_spouse = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

on doing `python manage.py makemigrations` I get the following error : `NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined`

Question : How should I use another record of the same model as a foreignkey in my current model

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because at that point `Profile` is not yet defined, you can use a string literal `'self'` in that case:

```
class Profile(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    full_name  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    husband_spouse = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Comment: your explanation totally makes sense after reading. Thank you so much.